# Timing settings change in Testwell CTC++

Tags: code-coverage, timing

How to change the Testwell CTC++ timing profile settings from clock ticks to milliseconds(ms)?
I searched the CTC++7.1.x manual and it states to change the ctc.ini file, but i couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In configuration file `ctc.ini` there are now the following settings:

```
TIMER = clock
TICK  = 1
EXECUTION_COST_TYPE = Clock ticks
```

If you are working at Windows with VC++, the `clock()` function already gives
its result in milliseconds. So you could just change to `ctc.ini`:

```
EXECUTION_COST_TYPE = milliseconds
```

and in the timing report you have "milliseconds" instead of "Clock ticks".
(Also `TICK = 1000` and `EXECUTION COST TYPE = seconds` would be a working set up).